# LVM encryption - start background processes

Tags: server, encryption, lvm

I used LVM encryption during Ubuntu installation in order to protect my files.
I am running on this machine mainly apache tomcat but the process doesn't start only after I enter passphrase.
The process is started after I enter the correct passphrase but even before login, so my apache tomcat is accessible before login, and I want it to be available before passphrase is entered, so this machine gives "apache tomcat" service, but is protected and only exposes what the apache tomcat process exposes.
Is this even possible ?
My goal is to have a local server running tomcat application, which even physical access to the device, which usually allows resetting the root user password under "recovery mode", will not allow accessing and reading the java code files and data files.
So as soon as the machine is powered up, it will provide apache tomcat service over LAN, but no further action will be required other then power up.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *I want it to be available before passphrase is entered* is absolutely NOT possible.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid this is the case. Probably it's because ubuntu can't read its own files without the passphrase so it can't execute the background processes.

Comment: No OS can. If you think otherwise you have a fundamental misunderstanding about what encryption is and what it does.